# Bracket assignment in Python

Tags: python, attributes, operator-overloading, variable-assignment, magic-methods

I would like to create a class that is able to do the following

```
class Test:
    # code here

test = Test()
test["test"] = 1
test.test  # returns 1
```

Is this possible in Python using magic methods (e.g. not inheriting from `dict`)?

Comment: test is not a data frame to  do like that

Comment: Okay, so in the other question you indicated that you did a little bit of research: "From looking at the source code it looks like the `__getattribute__` hook is being used, which is different from `__getattr__`" So - what happened when you **looked for those terms in the official Python language documentation**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could override `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` using `getattr` and `setattr`:

```
class Test:
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return getattr(self, key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        setattr(self, key, value)


test = Test()
test["test1"] = 1
print(test.test1)
```

Using this method, you can also set from the attribute and get from the square bracket operator:

```
test = Test()
test.test2 = 2
print(test["test2"])
```

If you wanted to use this among many classes then you could turn this into a base class:

```
class ItemAttributes:
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return getattr(self, key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        setattr(self, key, value)


class Test(ItemAttributes):
    pass
```